# Android SDK Build Tool Multiple Versions

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I need to know, Do we need to install every Android SDK Build Tool, or only the latest one will be sufficient?.

See this image for reference,

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple instances of Android SDK Build-Tools, Bug or Feature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785584/multiple-instances-of-android-sdk-build-tools-bug-or-feature)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quote from official android [website](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html):

> Build Tools is a component of the Android SDK required for building
>   Android application code. The latest version of these tools is
>   included in the SDK starter package and installed in the
>   /build-tools/ directory.
>
> You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by
>   downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. By
>   default, the Android SDK uses the most recent downloaded version of
>   the Build Tools. If your projects depend on older versions of the
>   Build Tools, the SDK Manager allows you to download and maintain
>   separate versions of the tools for use with those projects.

To make it short,if your project is using an OLDER version of apis (like 2.2 etc), it **might** make sense to use the build tools that were supplied to it.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/index.html) to know more about the build tools.

But, having said that, there is **NO NEED TO INSTALL OLDER VERSIONS** of the build tools. You should always use the latest
Android SDK build tools are used to debug, build, run and test an Android application,so the latest update will always have the most refined of features.

But of course, this is only for the final android app. If you want to use the version specific features of the build tools, you will need to download the respective build-tools.

Quoting The comment below for easier readability :

> It's more if you created custom build scripts (Ant, Gradle, etc.) that
>   assumed certain command-line switches for the build tools (dx, aapt,
>   etc.), you can stick with a particular version of those build tools.
>   Otherwise, developers tend to move to the most recent version of those
>   tools, for better performance, bug fixes, and the like

Comment: I am developing an app that will support api 14 and onwards, the latest version of Build Tool and SDK is enough to make it work ? No need for all of the SDKs and build tools ?

Comment: Build tools has got nothing to do with the APIs. Build tools are ONLY for the developer

Comment: "To make it short,if your project is using an OLDER version of apis (like 2.2 etc), it might make sense to use the build tools that were supplied to it." -- that's not really the use case. It's more if you created custom build scripts (Ant, Gradle, etc.) that assumed certain command-line switches for the build tools (**`dx`**, **`aapt`**, etc.), you can stick with a particular version of those build tools. Otherwise, developers tend to move to the most recent version of those tools, for better performance, bug fixes, and the like.

Comment: To second what CommonsWare said, this sentence should be **deleted** from the answer: "*if your project is using an OLDER version of apis (like 2.2 etc), it might make sense to use the build tools that were supplied to it.*".  There is **NO** connection between supporting older **API**s and using older **BUILD TOOLS**.  (As other answers say, there *might* be a need for older build tools, if you are using a third party library that was built using an older version, and never updated. But even then it isn't because of the API they were targeting.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any 3rd party libraries or support libraries then no you dont need to install everything but some libraries (google play services and the support library for example) require you to install other SDK's

Comment: So only the last build tool is enough for my app to work ? and similar is the case when installing the SDK ?

Comment: as long as the SDK you are targeting in your app has been downloaded yes

Comment: If my app is to work on devices from API 14 and above then the latest version of SDK is enough ? or I need to have all APIs from 14 to latest ?

Comment: downloading the latest SDK is enough for your app to work, you do not need to download everything unless a library needs you to

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it is recommended you install the latest version of the SDK Build tools. The older versions are left there for backward compatibility, that is if your projects depend on older versions of the Build Tools. I've resolved many errors in my projects by just referencing older versions of the build tools.But most importantly, you are better off with the latest version.

Comment: Re *"I've resolved many errors in my projects by just referencing older versions of the build tools."* I've never encountered this. What was a typical error message you received? When this happened, was that because the latest version had introduced a bug, that had not yet been fixed in that version? Or are you using custom build scripts? Third-party libraries that were not yet compatible with the latest build tools?